# Conditional error with a listing result

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Apollogies first for what is likely a dumb question. I'm new to Wordpress and PHP so I'm already over my head. I am concerned about this part of the code in lists-categories-posts/default.php which checks if there's a result and give an error if not:

```
if ( count( $this->catlist->lcp_categories_posts) == 0 )
{
  $lcp_display_output .= '<li>No results</li>';
}
```

I just need a different error when there is no result *but* when in a particular category ('news'). I modified the error code but I'm getting identical result.

```
if ( count( $this->catlist->lcp_categories_posts) == 0 )
{
  if ( in_category( 'news' )) {
    $lcp_display_output .= '<li>No news results</li>';
  } else {
    $lcp_display_output .= '<li>No results</li>';
  }
}
```

I'm trying to filter the error but it doesn't seem to evaluate the category at all. It always falls to the last `else` statement.

I really need some help...sigh.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/

Comment: Are you sure that you have a category called `news`?

Comment: I do actually - it does exist. That much I can find..  ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you do here is first check the `lcp_categories_posts` if is empty and then you check if it is in the category `news`.

I think that this is always going to be false since the `lcp_categories_posts` will be empty and therefore it will not belong to any category.

So your check for the category should go somewhere else.

Comment: I was beginning to think I had this inside-out, as you suggest. I'm trying alternatives but as long as I know I have the in_category() part right, it's a great help. I tried evaluating in the first statement and didn't get very far.

`if( count( $this->catlist->lcp_categories_posts) == 0 ) && in_category( 'careers' ) )`

then I could just use an else and be done.

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered is that the plugin that was generating the error kept the category_id private, but I found a different way:

```
if( count( $this->catlist->lcp_categories_posts) == 0 )
{      
    if ( $this->catlist->get_category_id() == get_cat_id("news") ) 
    {
        $lcp_display_output .= '<li>No News Results</li>';            
    } 
    else
    {
        $lcp_display_output .= '<li>No results</li>';    
    }    
}
```